# Laravel - How to use faker in PHPUnit test?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

It's giving me this error when I run the test:

> undefined variable $faker.

This is the WithFaker file.

https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.5/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/WithFaker.php

```
<?php

namespace Tests\Unit;

use App\User;
use Tests\TestCase;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\WithFaker;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\RefreshDatabase;

class LoginTest extends TestCase
{

    use WithFaker;

    /**
     * A basic test example.
     *
     * @return void
     */

    /** @test */
    public function test_example()
    {

        $user = User::create([
            'username' => $faker->firstName(),
        ]);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 112, accepted):

You have to use `$this->faker->firstName()` not just `$faker->firstName()`

**Update 1**

Now when we use `WithFaker` Trait `$this->faker` will give us `null`, to get around this make sure to call `$this->setupFaker()` first.

e.g.

```
class SomeFactory
{
    use WithFaker;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->setUpFaker();
    }

}
```

credit @Ebi

Comment: For ones who come to this later, be aware that by using the WithFaker trait you will receive null on `$this->faker`. To handle this issue, you need to call `$this->setupFaker()` before calling the `$this->faker`.

Comment: Thanks @Ebi for spot

Comment: and you need to add `use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\WithFaker;` to your imports! Why is everybody ignoring this important part?

Comment: With Laravel 8 this seems to be a lot smoother. Simply add `use WithFaker;` and `$this->faker` is now available to all the tests.

Comment: @Sliq It's in the default stub for Laravel tests already.

Answer (score 43):

For anyone coming here from 2021. We no longer require the addition of

```
$this->setUpFaker();
```

You only need to include the trait as described in the accepted answer.

Comment: and add `use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\WithFaker;` to your imports

Answer (score 17):

once you completed installation of Faker.
include autoload file and create instance

```
$faker = \Faker\Factory::create();
$faker->firstname();
$faker->lastname();
```

For more information [visit](https://packagist.org/packages/fzaninotto/faker)

Answer (score 0):

check you seed function run (Faker $faker).

Answer (score 0):

From Laravel 9, the simplest option is the `fake()` helper:

> The fake function resolves a Faker singleton from the container, which can be useful when creating fake data in model factories, database seeding, tests, and prototyping views.

```
fake()->name()
fake()->unique()->safeEmail()
fake('it_IT')->name() // to overwrite default faker locale (from config.php)
```

[Official docs here.](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/helpers#method-fake)